# sails.js / socket.io sending destroyed, but not created

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

I'm using v0.10.

Simple blueprint request for a messaging app (my model is named message)

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

//initiate the request
socket.request('/message', {}, function(users) {});
socket.on('message', function(m){
  console.log(m)
});
```

Using postman to to delete a message sends the delete to the client, however create does not send anything.  Thank you.

UPDATE:

created this repo to reproduce the issues:  https://github.com/jamescharlesworth/testProject

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Upgrading search that page for "socket" and there you'll find the differences on sails 0.10.

The most important one now is that instead of the "type of message", the first parameter of the "on" is the model. As it was previously used to call "message" to one of the types of messages, perhaps there is a remaining bug or something that filters your "message" model notifications when creating.

Have you tried naming your model different? Just to validate that the issue is with your model's name.

Additionally: if you want some transparent binding of models into an angular app, you can do it seamlessly with angular-sails-bind:

https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind

I made it for my own project and then decided to put it as a separated library so everybody could benefit and I could have my first experience developing a bower package.

I hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks, however i am using the upgraded api using the model identity and not a generic 'message' for `on`.  I thought it could be related to the naming convention of the model as well, but it seems to be happening with any other model. You can see an [example](https://github.com/jamescharlesworth/testProject).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using autosubscribe: ['destroy', 'create', 'update'],

while in sails 0.10 they have with "ed":

> - The events that were formerly create, update, and destroy are now created, updated, and destroyed.

That may be your issue.